# If Statement VHDL

Tags: hardware, vhdl, if-statement

Can some one explain why the golden rule when writing VHDL is that the if-then-else statement must be in a process. Is it because inside the process, the statements are executed sequentially, while outside they're not.

Answer (score 12):

The simple answer is "because that's how the syntax of the language is"!

If you want to select from some options with code *not* in a process you can do:

```
sig <= a when sel = 1 else
       b when sel = 2 else 
       default_value;
```

or

```
with sel select
   sig <= a when 1,
          b when 2,
          default_value when others;
```

[See here for many examples of a mux](http://www.quicknet.se/hdc/hdl/educaton/mux4_1/index.htm)

Comment: The author is correct, it's like that because that's the way it is.  If's outside of a process are simple decision trees (and-or select logic). However for completeness I would add that there is a form of IF that exists outside of a process, it's called GENERATE and works a bit like #ifdef  ....  #endif in C.

Comment: At first I thought I was severely hampered because of this when I wanted to make a small block that switched off several signals *outside* a process, but I learned you can use the `when - else` and still use multiple signals after the `when`.  Such as `sig <= a when (OPCODE = "000" and EN = "1"`

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think the main reason that if statements need to be in a process is that an if statement can potentially assign to more than one signal, if you wanted to do the same thing outside of a process you would need to use more than one conditional signal assignment.

For example:

```
process(C0, C1, A, B, C) is
begin
  if C0 = '1' then
    F <= A;
    G <= C;
  elsif C1 = '1' then
    F <= B;
    G <= B;
  else
    F <= C;
    G <= A;
  end if;
end process;
```

The equivalent conditional signal assignments outside of the process would be:

```
F <= A when C0 = '1' else B when C1 = '1' else C;
G <= C when C0 = '1' else B when C1 = '1' else A;
```

Answer (score -1):

if else statement :-

Syntax:

```
if then
   statements
   ...
[
elsif then
   statements
   ...
else
   statements
   ...
]
endif;
```

for more information please check [this](http://electronicsgyan.com/ifelsestatement.aspx)